# Что теперь юзать вместо соли? password_hash

Tags: php, php7

Хочу использовать функцию password_hash. В [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php) написано:

> Предостережение Настоятельно рекомендуется использовать автоматическую
>   генерацию соли. Данная функция самостоятельно создаст хорошую соль,
>   если вы не будете ей мешать подсовывая свою.
>
> Как было замечено выше, опция salt была объявлена устаревшей в PHP 7.0
>   и будет вызывать соответствующее предупреждение. Поддержка ручного
>   задания соли может быть удалена в более новых версиях.

Как это понимать? Если соль генерируется рандомно, то я получу разный хэш, и как мне потом сравнить с записанным хешем, если они будут отличаться?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php "Обратите внимание, что password_hash() возвращает алгоритм, стоимость и соль как части хеша. Таким образом, вся необходимая для проверки информация включена в него. Это позволяет производить проверку без необходимости хранить все эти данные раздельно" http://php.net/manual/ru/book.password.php

Comment: @qwabra хорошо бы некие пояснения, а не просто цитаты и ссылки, а то это выглядит "как нарисовать сову"

Comment: соль как части хеша, как часть хэша - соль

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/76/Argon2.png/431px-Argon2.png

Comment: а что за сова ?

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый @qwabra хотел сказать, что надо использовать [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php) для проверки соответствия хеша паролю, а не обычное "==".

Answer (score 0):

Суть в том, что один и тот-же пароль, может генерировать с разной солью, причем одинаковой так-таковой не будет, так-как, используется привязка к времени.

```
function password($password, $hash = '') {
    if ($hash) {
        return password_verify($password, $hash);
    } else if ($password) {
        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, [
            'cost' => 11
        ]);
    }
}
$password = 'password';
$hashs = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 3;  ++$i) {
    $hashs[] = password($password);
}
var_dump($hashs);
```

Вывод (всегда будет разным):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(60) "$2y$11$U.pByOtimdolMwM0ltXYvO3lM/ottr0W5qGLcYHhGdL1ql1OndtEC"
  [1]=>
  string(60) "$2y$11$ZnmQz1hiZkvpdO5RXM5qCeY9N8LVgt5b6ONGBGfr4ZQxmd5WTdGDW"
  [2]=>
  string(60) "$2y$11$I5p4vJScXYgea1invjg3F..4zC.5xNSqbflNTS/RxfpyFJ2lUZ/8W"
}
```

Проверяем:

```
foreach($hashs as $hash) {
    var_dump(password($password, $hash));
}
```

Вывод:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Это значит. что все 3 хеша равны `password`.